# What does G.U stand for?

Tags: .hack

in *.hack//ROOTS* and *.hack//G.U*, the guild Raven is actually the CC Copr Organization "Project G.U" who's focus is on AI, partially the AIDA, the Morgana Mode Gone Epitaphs and Aura.

But what does the G.U stand for anyway? i am well aware that in Terminal Disk each "episode" is named using the letters G and U like *Graceless Unison* and *Guide to an Uprising* but it it was never stated which one of those (if any) was the G.U used by CC Corp. the only 2 letter Acronym they explain is RA which is Rebirth Aura.

So what does G.U stand for in Project G.U?

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia: [.hack//G.U.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack//G.U.)

> Matsuyama has stated that the acronym "G.U." has twelve meanings related to the plot of the games but the central theme is "growing up" in many respects.